# Javascript + Google Maps, using two markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, marker

First - In the HTML I have two objects:

```
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="directions"></div>
```

My main concern right now is the map. The page first loads with a map and a default marker drop, and there is a textbox for a user to type in an address which I will eventually write the code to get the directions from point A to point B, but I cannot get the second marker to drop onto the map. Here is my current code:

(pretend there is an actual address listed as "home", I'm removing what is actually there)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({address: "address A"}, function(results) {
    var homeLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
    alert(homeLatLng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9, 
        center: homeLatLng, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map").get(0), mapOptions);

    var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: homeLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: "Home"
    }); 

}); // end of geocode, map              

$("#get_directions").click(function() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    if (address.length < 1) {
        alert("Input field is empty.");
    }
    else {
        alert(address);
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK'){
                alert(status);
                var destLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                alert(destLatLng);

                var destMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: destLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Destination"
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Could not locate address.\nReason: " + status);
            }
        }); // end geocode


    } // end outer if else
}); // end click

}); // end of ready
```

EDIT: Got the points to drop by switching things around a bit and using the following (I stored the long/lat values in the LL variables) ...

```
var drops = [
                [homeLL, 'home'],
                [destLL, 'destination']
            ];

            for (var i=0; i<drops.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: drops[i][0],
                    map: map,
                    title: drops[i][1]
                });
            }
```

Comment: "Address A" puts in the first Marker, and you see "Home" when you hover over it?.... or do you see "Destination"?

Comment: It displays the text "Home"

Comment: Can you add fiddle link to demonstrate problem